# Is there a better way than scoping to apply user-specific changes to models in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In an application I'm attempting to update to Rails 3.2 which was working fine in Rails 3.0, there are some scoping rules which use `with_scope` to apply user-specific manipulations of the model depending on the user's permissions.

Trivial model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value
end
```

Testing scope behaviour:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "scoping for create" do
    Item.with_scope({ :create => { :value => 42 }}) do
      item = Item.create!
      assert_equal 42, item.value
    end
  end

  test "scoping for create when caller tries to override" do
    Item.with_scope({ :create => { :value => 42 }}) do
      item = Item.create!(:value => 37)
      assert_equal 42, item.value
    end
  end

  test "scoping for update" do
    Item.with_scope({ :create => { :value => 42 }}) do
      item = Item.create!
      item.update_attributes!(:value => 37)
      assert_equal 42, item.value
    end
  end
end
```

Under Rails 3.2, "scoping for create" passes and the other two fail. It seems like in Rails 3.2 (possibly in 3.1 as well, I'm not sure), `:create` now only helps initialise the model on construction, whereas in the past versions, it would overwrite any other values you had set at save time.

In the real application, the decision of which scope to use depends on the user's permissions.

I do realise that I could clean the map before passing it through from the controller, but that seems to result in putting business logic into the controller.

So, is there perhaps a proper way to deal with this sort of current-user-dependant business logic?

Comment: I have a bit confusion, with_scope seems to work well for me as same as the api says. your code works unexpected ?

Comment: It certainly works differently in 3.2 from 3.0, but I don't know what's expected because the docs are very vague on the subject (they don't even say what :create does!)

Comment: Or can you use cache sweeper instead of this? cache sweeper can observe multiple models before or after saving with controller variables , I usually use it such as your case here.